# Strange HTML attributes

Tags: html

We have recently started seeing these attributes injected into the HTML on one of our web sites:

```
lpcachedvistime="1316107000" lpcachedvisval="1"
```

Any idea what these are and where they are coming from?

A Google search reveals a couple of people asking the same question (with no answers) and of course a number of web pages that also have these attributes scattered throughout the HTML.

Comment: How are these attributes injected? Comment forms? CMS? More details would be very useful

Comment: Is there a proxy between you and the server (either opaque or transparent)? Has any software been installed on the server recently?

Comment: Is this in the 'view source' html, or in the 'live' DOM (with Web inspector, Dragonfly, Firebug, etc)?

Answer (score 4):

This is kind of an old question, and Tim already more or less provided the answer, but this is an attribute that the LastPass browser extension will add to form elements as it scans the page for inputs it thinks are related to username/password entry.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see what plugins/extentions might be running in your internet browser. I had Skype recently install a plugin into my google chrome browser which then started adding extra html.

Note though it doesnt actually add this to your "real" html, it is only added through the browser. So other people will not see this.

Answer (score 0):

I have one recreate scenario for this behavior:
When entering a form using fck editor, I can see these attributes injected.